# ASP.NET MVC 4 Saving Model List Items in Edit View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm trying to save below project Model

```
public partial class Project: BaseModel
{
    public Project()
    {
        ProjectUsers = new List<ProjUser>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name="Project ID")]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    public virtual List<ProjUser> ProjectUsers { get; set; }
}
```

ProjUser Model

```
public partial class ProjUser: BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjUserID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectID")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public bool? Signatories { get; set; }

}
```

The Users are populated via a separate database and the link between the project and user are maintains via the ProjUser model, UserID value.

```
public partial class User : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "dispUserName" , ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

In the view i'm populating the list of users as a selectable (JqueryUI) and selecting the users who are available in the project.

```
@model Impetro.Models.Project
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProjectSettings";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project Settings</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectID)
        <div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
}
<h3>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProjectUsers)</h3>
@{
    var pojectUserIDs = from pu in Model.ProjectUsers
                        select new { pu.UserID };

    String userIDstr = "";
    foreach (var user in pojectUserIDs)
    {
        userIDstr = userIDstr + "#" + user.UserID.ToString() + ";";
    }
}
@Html.Hidden("userValues", userIDstr, "id='userValues'")
<table data-impetro-uitype="selectable" data-impetro-selectorvalues="#userValues" id="projUserGrd">
    @foreach (var user in ViewBag.Users as IEnumerable<Impetro.Models.Global.User>)
    {
        <tr id="@user.UserID" class="ui-widget-content"><td>@user.UserName</td> <td>@Html.CheckBox("chk" + @user.UserID) @Html.Label("chk" + @user.UserID, "PO Signatory")</td></tr>
    }
</table>
```

The JS to convert the above table to a selectable and to select the already added users.

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-impetro-uitype='selectable']").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
    })
    .selectable({
        filter: "tr",
        create: function (event, ui) {
            var selectable = $(this);
            var valueEle = selectable.attr("data-impetro-selectorvalues");
            var valArr = $(valueEle).val().split(";");
            for (var i = 0; i < valArr.length; i++) {
                if (valArr[i] == "") {
                    continue;
                }
                var id = valArr[i];
                selectable.find(id).addClass("ui-selected");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How can the changes to the projusers list be captured in the model?
Btw: Is there an easier method to select the values on initial load itself, which supports tracking the projUser list changes

Thanks in Advance

As Requested by lnanikian here is the GET Action for the controller. I still did not write the POST Action for this, becos im still in doubt about how to proceed with saving the details into the list.

```
public ActionResult ProjectSettings(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Users = userRepository.All;
        return View(projectRepository.All
               .Where(p => p.ProjectID == id).SingleOrDefault());
    }
```

Comment: you want to update model on server side the user you select for project?

Comment: yes the project needs to be updated (added / Removed / Updated) with userID and Signitary information.

Comment: Can we see the `Action` in the `Controller`? Also After your form you could put the second part yo a partial view and you will put your code not in the view. Better to separate layers.

Comment: @lnanikian i have added the action i have done up to now.
And yes i agree it would be good to have the second part in a separate partial view, but becos i plan to included the selected users, in the form and send it back to the server. i kept it in the same view.
If i can get a method to send the details in the same post method and get it saved, then having this in the partial view is ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well. Let say when you click on the checkBox of the User he must be updated to the project? Whatn you can also do is create an `Action` who will save your User for the project.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUserToProj(int userId){
 //retreive the User by the Id with a Linq query or
 //just add to ProjUsers the Id of the UserId with other importants informations you can
 //pass via th eparameters 
}
```

And then in your view, in your `JS function` an Ajax Method who will be called let's say if your your user is checked then you call the `Action`

```
$(function () {
   $("[data-impetro-uitype='selectable']").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.metaKey = true;
    })
    .selectable({
    filter: "tr",
    create: function (event, ui) {
        var selectable = $(this);
        var valueEle = selectable.attr("data-impetro-selectorvalues");
        var valArr = $(valueEle).val().split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < valArr.length; i++) {
            if (valArr[i] == "") {
                continue;
            }
            var id = valArr[i];
            selectable.find(id).addClass("ui-selected");
        }
    }
});

$('#check').bind('change', function () {

   if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {//You can ask a question here by a popup
     var userID= $("userId") //You retreive userId in the line by wise selection

     $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AddUserToProj","ControllerName")",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id = $userID },
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            //  process the results from the server
            alert('done')

            });

        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
  }
 else
  {
    // unchecked, You can call a Deletion Method if you create another Action to do that
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: i saw this method, but this is not the method i want.
if you can see my view i have the project title also to edit.
my aim is to giv the user one save button which will save all the information.

Comment: I understand your points. So you can also try to put your table to your Form. Then pass the to controller on your submit and you can retrieve it by `Request.QueryString['ids']`. but you will have a problem all users will be sent. Thinking of a client solution when you check a user, you put the value in a field in the form As you are able to manipulate the change. So when you will pass the value of the form you are certain that those ids are sent. and in your controller you will test if not null then assign

Comment: The solution mentioned by lnanikian is the way to got.
But be aware, there is a considarable amount of work both FE (JS) and BE string manipulation work to extract the changes and push them to the DB.